# Trigger One Jquery Function With Another Jquery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below I have a table row where a calculation happens upon input in `.quantity` and the result of that calculation is placed in `.amount2`.  This works just fine and works as you see below.

```
                    <tr class="manifest-row">
                      <td width = 17.5% class="productCode" onchange="populateProduct(this)">{{form.ProductCode}}</td>
                      <td width = 32.5% class="description">{{form.DescriptionOfGoods}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="quantity" oninput="calculateUnit(this)">{{form.UnitQty}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="unitType">{{form.Type}}</td>
                      <td width = 10.5% class="price" oninput="calculate(this)">{{form.Price}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="amount2">{{form.Amount}}</td>
                    
                    </tr>
```

JS

```
function calculateUnit(el) {
    // Find the row containing this cell
    var row = el.closest("tr");

    // Get the quantity from the `input` in the `.quantity` cell in this row
    var unitQty = el.querySelector('.quantity input').value;

    // Get the price from the `input` in this cell (could use `e.target` instead)
    var price = row.querySelector('.price input').value;

    // Do the calculation, assign to the `input` in the `.amount` cell in this row
    var lineTotal = unitQty * price;

    row.querySelector('.amount2 input').value = lineTotal;

}
```

The issue is that there can be many rows, and I have a separate function which sums all the values in the inputs where class is `.amount2` and places that sum in a field `#id_InvoiceTotal`. But this function below does not trigger properly on input because it is being filled instead by the function above. So how can I make the function above trigger the function below?  I've seen `.trigger()` in my online searches but I don't understand how to apply it here.

```
<script>
$(document).on("input", ".amount2", function() {
  var total = 0;
  var i = 0;
  $('#form_set .amount2').each(function() {

    total += parseInt($('#id_form-'+(i)+'-Amount').val());
    i++;
    $('#id_InvoiceTotal').val(total);
  })
});

</script>
```

Comment: Just move it to a function and call it from `calculateUnit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the same function with just two additional statements like this :

```
function calculateUnit(el) {
  let total = 0;
  var row = el.closest("tr");
  var unitQty = el.querySelector('.quantity input').value;
  var price = row.querySelector('.price input').value;

  var lineTotal = unitQty * price;

  row.querySelector('.amount2 input').value = lineTotal;

  document.querySelectorAll(".amount2 input").forEach(function(item){
    total += item.value / 1;
  });

  document.querySelector("#id_InvoiceTotal").value = total;

}
```

Comment: thank you this is a good answer but the issue is that since this is happening on input, ```total``` is added to when the user backspaces.  So for example if quantity is 10 and price is 10, amount is initially 100.  If I backspace the 0 out of quantity it then adds 10 (1 x 10) and adds that to the total.

Comment: I am really sorry. I missed that. I have updated the code.

Comment: hm now it just returns 0.  could you elaborate on what you are trying to do for my knowledge?

Comment: Basically, when you would change input in `.quantity` element, the function in code will be triggered. `total` will be initialized on each call with `0`. I added a forEach loop which will iterate through all the `.amount input` elements and add their value to `total`.

Comment: @GXM100 I just checked it. Actually there was a typographical mistake. I had used `.amount` in place of `.amount2`. It will work now, I have updated the code.

Comment: ah perfect! should've caught that myself sorry for that.  I appreciate your help!